# Django Rest framework replacing my currently authenticated user with AnonymousUser whenever I call it via ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to add a few interactive things the to Django admin page via a simple RESTful api and Javascript. Should be simple, but I'm facing a weird issue where every single one of my requests from javascript is returning a `403` authorization error. Note that this only applies to js. I can hit the url from a browser just fine and do all the basic CRUD stuff.

The code is very basic.

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    type: 'PATCH',
    url: 'path/to/my/endpoint,
    data: {
        aParam: someValue,
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken')
    },
    success: doSomething,
    error: doSomething
});
```

**Python**

```
class MyObjectDetail(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer

  authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication,)
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

I initially suspected that the session ID wasn't being sent, and thus that was why everything was failing due to permissions. However, the session cookie is indeed sent in the ajax POST and picked up by the Django middleware. Django pulls my Admin session with no problems. However, (after a *lot* of debugging) I've traced the User rewrite to a `dispatch` method in Django Rest Framework -- specifically, a call to `self.initialize_request`. After that call returns, my Admin user gets swapped out for one of rest Framework's `AnonymouseUser`s.

I'm totally lost. I spent about 2 hours stepping through with a debugger, but still don't understand why my user is being swapped out. Has anyone faced this before? Am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: @KevinBrown  Ah., well, I feel like a dunce! Yeah, it was the CSRF not being in the header that was throwing things off. As soon as I stuck it in the right spot things started behaving as they should. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the 403 error should include a friendly message explaining what the issue is, I think in this case you will find that the message is complaining about a lack of CSRF token.

> Note that this only applies to js. I can hit the url from a browser just fine and do all the basic CRUD stuff.

There are only a few things different between JS and the browser, and none of them are directly caused by Django REST framework. The one that you are probably hitting is how CSRF is dealt with in AJAX requests: [the CSRF token should be passed in through a header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax). Right now that means changing your JavaScript to

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

function addCsrfToken (xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
}

$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    type: 'PATCH',
    url: 'path/to/my/endpoint',
    data: {
        aParam: someValue
    },
    success: doSomething,
    error: doSomething,
    beforeSend: addCsrfToken
});
```

Note that while [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax) recommends setting this header globally, it explicitly disallows the token from being sent in cross-origin requests. It looks like (from the `withCredentials`) in your code that you are accessing an API on a different domain.

> Django pulls my Admin session with no problems.

This is most likely because hitting the page in your browser doesn't trigger a CSRF check, and the browsable API handles CSRF for you.

> After that call returns, my Admin user gets swapped out for one of rest Framework's `AnonymouseUser`.

Django REST framework only deals with the anonymous user in one place, and [that's when authentication fails](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/0e21f1c4f4cd91551cd6021a8ca03a6911feac44/rest_framework/request.py#L476). So while your request may be authenticated through Django, it likely isn't being authenticated through Django REST framework.